# Set Multilple Attributes at Once in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties

I recognized, when I wanna set the same attribute for multiple objects/controls (here labels) in c# I'll have to type the same code very often.
This often looks like this:

```
string s = "one attribute";
label1.Text = s;
label2.Text = s;
label3.Text = s;
label4.Text = s;
label5.Text = s;
```

Isn't there any way to do this much quicker and with less code?
I'm imaging something like this:

```
string s = "one attribute";
(label1 && label2 && label3 && label4 && label5).Text = s;
```

**ANSWER:**

```
string s = "one attribute";
label1.Text =
label2.Text =
label3.Text =
label4.Text =
label5.Text = s;
```

Comment: `.Text` is a *Property*.  `Attributes` are something else.

Comment: @Plutonix: Except that "attribute" is the correct formal OOP term for what .NET calls a field or property... conflicting terminology is always confusing.

Comment: If you're going to be doing stuff like this often you should add all of the controls to a collection and iterate over them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it all in one line like so.

```
label1.Text = label2.Text = label3.Text = label4.Text = label5.Text = "one attribute";
```

**Edit :** If you want to keep labels in an array then here is another way to do it without actually writing out the foreach loop each time.

```
Label[] labels = new[] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
Array.ForEach(labels, x => { x.Text = "one attribute"; });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! It's so easy I didn't even recognized that option.

Comment: But it does! And it's exactly what I needed. :D

Comment: The only thing I can't believe is how many upvotes I received, btw an alternative would be to create a method devoted to doing this if you are setting the Text property quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
foreach(var label in new [] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 })
{
    label.Text = "one attribute";
}
```

If you're doing this in several places, it might be more convenient to store that array somewhere:

```
IEnumerable<Label> labelsToUpdate = new [] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };

foreach(var label in labelsToUpdate)
{
    label.Text = "one attribute";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "one attribute";
label1.Text = 
label2.Text = 
label3.Text = 
label4.Text = 
label5.Text = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can assign multiple variables like:

```
label1.Text = label2.Text = "Whatever";
```

However i hate this. At some point in the future you might want to refactor the code and not set the variables in this way.

I would rather do:

```
String InitStr = "Whatever";
label1.Text = InitStr;
label2.Text = InitStr;
label3.Text = InitStr;
label4.Text = InitStr;
```

In the future if you decide you want to change the value of label3 then its much cleaner.

```
String InitStr = "Whatever";
label1.Text = InitStr;
label2.Text = InitStr;
label3.Text = "new whatever";
label4.Text = InitStr;
```